# how to install ubuntu from usb if bios have no such option

Tags: boot, usb

How to install xubuntu from usb if bios have no such option.my pc have no cd drive. it is a pentium iii, 128 MB RAM, 20 GB HDD .

Comment: what is your current OS

Comment: windows 95, but system have virus... its cd rom drive is complaint

Comment: helo Rick Green - Turbo  please help

Comment: If your computer runs Windows 95, it probably can't support booting via USB.

Comment: If Windows cannot recognize the CD-ROM, it does not mean that the system cannot recognize the CD-ROM. As long as your BIOS can recognize the drive, you can boot from the Ubuntu CD.

Comment: Is this a Laptop or a Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

There is a handy page in the Ubuntu documentation for situations such as these. See options 4, 5, 6 and 7: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Installation_without_a_CD